# Accessing derived class methods from base class method or another suggestion

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, overloading, variadic-templates

Consider the following code (I know you may think this is a weird design. I'm open to constructive suggestions):

```
class Graphics
{
    // ...

public:
    template <typename Type, typename... Types>
    void draw(Type const& object, Types const&... objects)
    {
        // ...
        addToBatch(object, objects...);
        // ...
    }

protected:
    void addToBatch(Type const& object, Types const&... objects)
    {
        _addToBatch(object);
        if constexpr (sizeof...(objects) > 0)
            addToBatch(objects...);
    }

    void _addToBatch(Rect rc, Brush b);
    void _addToBatch(std::pair<Rect, Brush> rcAndBrush)
    {
        _addToBatch(rcAndBrush.first, rcAndBrush.second);
    }
    void _addToBatch(TextLayout const& tl, Brush b, Point origin);
    // ... etc
}


class SpecializedGraphics : public Graphics
{
    // ...

protected:
    // here I want to implement methods for specialized complex processing,
    // which will use _addToBatch methods from base class
    void _addToBatch(Entry const& e);
    void _addToBatch(Menu const& menu);
    // etc
}

int main()
{
    Rect rcClient;
    Brush brush;
    Entry e;
    Menu menu;
    // etc

    SpecializedGraphics gfx;
    gfx.draw(
        std::make_pair(rcClient, brush),
        e,
        menu,
        // etc
    )
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me a compiler error. I suppose that is because Graphics::draw is the base class method and has no access to methods of the derived class. How can I properly work around this problem? One solution that comes to my mind is simply copy/paste the definition of the draw method from the base class to the derived class (name hiding). Any better suggestions? Because why do I need to define what is already defined.

Comment: Use `virtual` functions

Comment: This means that I have to declare a virtual method with a known signature in the base class. But why does general graphics should even know about all this complexity?

Comment: How is the base class supposed to call functions it doesn't know about? A base class does not know every single class that inherits from it (and what would it do if it wasn't actually a class that has those functions?)

Comment: @UnholySheep you can do that by using pure virtual functions in Base class.

Comment: @SeventhSon84 that's exactly what I suggested. But that still means that the base class has to "know" about the existence of these virtual functions

Comment: Another point against this suggestion is that if I need another specialized graphics in the future then I'll have to implement unnecessary functions for this particular specialized graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You can uso pure virtual functions,
in your base class change the declaration of methods you want to left implementations to derived classes like so:

```
virtual void _addToBatch(Rect rc, Brush b) = 0;
```

by doing so the method is now declared as pure virtual,

inside your Specialized classes now you must define those functions:

```
class SpecializedGraphics : public Graphics
{
 protected:
  void _addToBatch(Rect rc, Brush b);
```

Comment: As I said in the comments, I don't think that the general graphics should know all this complexity of the specialized graphics. Maybe general draw function can be marked as virtual and reimplemented in the specialized graphics, though it will be exactly the same.

Comment: But, unfortunately, I can't make a virtual template function. Well, I'm left with stupid copy/pasting.